# Create numeric indicator at a navigation view item android

Tags: android, drawer, navigationview

I just created a navigation view drawer using menu:

```
<group
    android:id="@+id/menu_top">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Camera" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow"/>
</group>
```

Now, I wonder how to add a numerical indicator on one of its items. Just like when Google Play Store having some updates on our installed apps. For example, item cart on screenshot below:

[image]

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Use `app:actionLayout` in your menu item, create custom `TextView` and set value to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Use `actionLayout` in your menu items:**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
    android:title="Camera"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/view_counter" />
```

**2) Create view_counter**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCounter" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
```

**3) Find `MenuItem` and set counter**

```
MenuItem mItem = mNavView.getMenu().findItem(nav_1); // Find navigation item
View view = mItem.getActionView();
if (view instanceOf TextView) { // Double check, returned view is TextView
    ((TextView) view).setText(count);
}
```